# How do I deal with this regex issue?

Tags: regex, delphi, parsing, extract

I need to extract a value from a hidden HTML field, have somewhat figured it out but I'm currently stuck.

My regex looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value=".*"
```

But this extracts the whole string from the HTML.

The string looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="123"/>
```

I need to extract the "value" from the string, it is always changing, but the "name" is always the same. Is there a way to extract it without doing another expression? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please define "without doing another expression".

Comment: @humble_coder Without creating another regex expression. I want to extract the value in one single expression(one line).

Comment: I'm sure I've got a T-shirt somewhere that says something about parsing HTML with regex........

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, is that the one with the message spelled out in stab wounds?

Comment: @David Heffernan if you can suggest me a free html parser component for delphi that is up to date, then I would use it. All the ones that work cost.

Comment: I always think about [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/960757).

Comment: @TLama Indeed that's what's on the T-shirt!!

Comment: How much do the components cost? How much time will it take you to cobble something together yourself that's sufficiently robust? How much is your time worth? If X < Y * Z, then just buy the component and get on with the real part of your project.

Comment: @Beta - Does that shirt actually exist? Because I would buy it.

Comment: @JustinMorgan, parse HTML with a regex and we'll come to your house and make one for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=<[^<>]+?name="form_id"[^<>]+value=")(.*)(?=")
```

Answer (score 1):

I just threw this together.  Basically you want to negate any ending > in your request.  So you'd likely want to do something of this nature:

```
<[^>]*hidden[^>]*value="(.*)"[^>]*>
```

And then read the first capture group ([Delphi instructions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html)). This keeps it as reasonably generic as possible although it does assume positional order on "hidden" and "value".

In order to find the value without regard for order you could use could use a slightly cleaner lookahead as was suggested:

```
 ^(?=.*name="form_id").*value="([^"]*)".*$
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the whole string, not only the value.

Comment: The value is in the first capture group.  Are you familiar with those?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, totally missed that one. The first capture group returns the value, do you mind posting an example if the order was changed? e.g if "value" came before "name"

Answer (score 0):

`<[a-zA-Z"= _^>]*value="(\d*)"/>`
I have tested this for your example.
If you want to extract for only input tag you can write:

```
<input[a-zA-Z"= _^>]*value="(\d*)"/>
```